# Need an sql query to find results joining two tables but comparing multiple rows in second table

Tags: mysql, sql

Below given are two sample tables

Table: post

```
id  title       desc             status
1   test        testdesc         active
2   test1       testdesc2        active
```

Table: post_meta

```
 id     post_id         meta_key          meta_value
 1        1             _customer_user    342
 2        1             date_registered   2019-03-21
 3        2             _customer_user    342
 4        2             date_registered   2019-03-22
```

I want an sql query to find those who registered on 2019-03-21 and are active. Want result like below.

```
id  cusomerid   registered_date   
1    342         2019-03-21
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: it's mysql dbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fddc11cb43bdd9f18aa7c7e0a18fdd59)**

```
select a.id, b.meta_Value as customerid, b1.meta_value as registrationdate
from post a left join post_meta b 
on a.id=b.post_id and b.meta_key='_customer_user'
left join post_meta b1 
on a.id=b1.post_id and b1.meta_key='date_registered'
where status='active' and b1.meta_value='2019-03-21'
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  customerid  registrationdate
1   342         2019-03-21
```

Comment: i'm getting an error: Operand should contain 2 column(s)

Comment: @tibinmathew, i've updated the answer - you can check now